# Execute a program opening a file in parent directory from parent directory in C++

Tags: c++, makefile

My project structure looks like this:

```
├── Makefile
├── data
├── src
│   ├── ...other code
│   └── main.cpp
└── bin
    └── out
```

The program will look into the parent directory and open a file put in there, the code opening the file looks like:

```
f.open("../data");
```

and it will generate some temporary files in `bin`(where the binary goes) with code like this:

```
f.open("temp");
```

My makefile looks like this:

```
SOURCES=src/main.cpp src/foo.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

EXECUTABLE=bin/out

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm src/*.o $(EXECUTABLE)

test:
    bin/out arg1 arg2

load:
    bin/out arg1 arg2

.PHONY: test load
```

Now, I can `make` from the parent directory, then go into the `bin`, execute the program. But the program cannot open the `data` in the parent directory if I just run `make load` or `make test` from the parent directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `cd` on a `make` recipe command :

```
test:
     cd bin; ./out arg1 arg2
```

Don't forget to `cd` in the same line where you are executing